# DISALLOW_PASSWORD_RESET not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to disable password change/reset feature from my wordpress website. I wrote these code inside the wp-config.php file. the code disabled edit theme file but still user or admin can generate new password from dashboard. please help me.

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_DELETE', true);
define('DISALLOW_PASSWORD_RESET', true);
```

Comment: Neither WordPress nor WooCommerce have code to support the `DISALLOW_PASSWORD_RESET` configuration parameter. You can probably find a plugin to control that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a function that uses the WordPress filter [`allow_password_reset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allow_password_reset/).

```
function disable_password_reset() {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );
```